# A folk-wisdom metaphor / mental image

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What's a word that describes a useful metaphorical precept? "Money is time" might be an example of a _______.

For some reason I am associating these (wrong) words with this one: allegory, syllogy, anecdote—so maybe it is similar to these.

"Analogy" might be the closest synonym I have thought of so far, similarly "analogue" almost works.

Bruce Lee's "be water" isn't an instruction to literally become water, but a metaphor to encourage flexibility and adaptability.

If I said "I am water" I would be using a _________.

Somehow I associate this word with sages and wise masters in the mountain. Like _______s could be used for expressing comprehensions about the Dao. "There is no spoon" kind of resonance.

Comment: These are all metaphors: using an element from a largely dissimilar set to bring out a point of comparison. 'John is a tiger / like a tiger' // 'Be a tiger, John!' etc are different expressions of a single metaphor with human tenor and 'tiger' vehicle, point of comparison 'fierce determination / toughness' (not long facial whiskers / a striped tail). 'All that glitters is not gold' is obviously used metaphorically most of the time, referring to enticing opportunities rather than Au, but is also a proverb. 'Look before you leap' is a maxim, advice offered concisely.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the word I am looking for is definitely not proverb, adage, or maxim. It might be aphorism or apothegm, but those sounds like they have to be statements of _truth_. So, which word from the dupe question is the answer to this question?

Comment: A 'metaphorical adage' works. You want a word combining the meanings 'metaphor' and 'adage' (you can look up adage). Some adages (expressions of folk-wisdom) give literal information / advice; others give advice by drawing analogies. // Looking for synonyms (hyponyms will also be given) of 'maxim' etc is the way for you to go now, but I doubt you'll find a close match.

Comment: @theonlygusti I think "idiom" might be the word you're looking for. From wiktionary: "An established expression whose meaning may not be not deducible from the literal meanings of its component words, often peculiar to a given language."

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I'm **sure** you yourself say "glisters". I'd put money on it.

Comment: @MelonDusk I don't actually want the word to imply "established". It should be able to be applied to off-the-cuff statements too, like the very first time someone said "the brain is a muscle" their conversation partner should have been able to say "wow that's a great _______"

Comment: @Old Brixtonian You'd lose.  And 'glitters' is the more common here. [Google 5-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+glitters+is+not+gold%2Cthat+glisters+is+not&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20glitters%20is%20not%20gold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20glisters%20is%20not%3B%2Cc0) And the one Tolkien inverts.

Comment: 'Money is time' dates from the 1830s and has been fairly widely used.  Folk-wisdom is handed down from generation to generation. If you want a term that includes new statements, 'epigram' works fine. Have you looked it up?

Comment: @EldwinAshworth I can't help but associate 'adage' with history. Adage isn't the word I was looking for when I asked this question.

Comment: epigram says "clever or amusing" (and has connotations with satirical poetry?) Instead of a witty remark, I want to describe deep, profound, meaningful remarks

Comment: although "aphorism" might be the word that I was hunting for, maybe we can't do better than it